# Using Torch with neural-style arts in AWS linux AMI, error loading module 'libjpeg' and <image.loadJPG> libjpeg package not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, machine-learning, amazon-ami, torch

As title, I use the AWS EC2 with AWS linux AMI to set the environment run the neural-style algorithm.

[Nerual-style](https://github.com/jcjohnson/neural-style)

I have install torch, Lua, Loadcaffe, Google protocal buffer and neural-style package succesfully.

When I try run the testing instruction :

```
th neural_style.lua -gpu -1 -print_iter -1
```

I got this :

```
/home/ec2-user/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:384: ...ec2-
user/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/luarocks/loader.lua:117: error loading  
module 'libjpeg' from file '/home/ec2-user/torch/install/lib/lua
/5.1/libjpeg.so':
libjpeg.so.62: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
warning: <libjpeg> could not be loaded (is it installed?)   
/home/ec2-user/torch/install/bin/luajit: /home/ec2-user/torch/install
/share/lua/5.1/dok/inline.lua:738: <image.loadJPG> libjpeg package not found, please install libjpeg
```

How can I correctly load the libjpeg package ???

Answer (score 3):

You are missing libjpeg. SSH to your AWS instance and run 
`sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev`.

Comment: Remember that you have to reinstall image afterwards `luarocks install image`